# NSDictionary description not returning utf8 characters?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary with utf8 strings as objects. Printing the objects prints the special characters as they should.

But utf8 characters do not get correctly printed out when I convert the dictionary to a string with the `description` method.

```
NSDictionary *test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Céline Dion" forKey:@"bla"];
NSLog(@"%@",[test objectForKey:@"bla"]); // prints fine
NSLog(@"%@",test);                       // does not print fine, é is replaced by \U00e
NSLog(@"%@",[test description]);         // also does not print fine
```

How can I print the NSDictionary while preserving utf8 characters?

Comment: Why do you need `-description`? Is it so important? Everything you need is `-valueForKey` (or `-objectForKey`) and *it* works fine.

Comment: I want to print out the whole request to a text view - yes it's just for development, but correctly printing utf8 characters would be nicer on the eye. And I want to know whether I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about what -description does, it's just for debugging.

Technically, you don't have UTF-8 strings. You have strings (which are Unicode). You don't know what NSString uses internally, and you shouldn't care. If you want a UTF-8 string (like when you're passing to a C API), use -UTF8String.

Comment: Remember that converting an object to a string calls `-description`.

Comment: You mean in NSLog? That's for debugging too.

Answer (score 0):

There **is** a way, but I can't check it at the moment:

```
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[test description] cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
NSLog(@"%@",decodedString);
```