# Save Special Character/Swedish/German Characters in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to save special characters/german/swedish character in `NSDictionary` and have to post this data to server, but the data saved in the dictionary is converted to some other format as in console output. I am trying to save this string as different typecasts but not getting.

As `NSDictionary`'s data type is generic, and while sending to POST its sent as in the modified format, I want to save this data in `NSDictionary` as it is, so that it can be sent in proper format to server and readable at server-end

My code is

```
NSString *playerName = @"Lëÿlã Råd Sölvê";  // dummy player name
NSLog(@"playerName: %@",playerName);

NSDictionary *postParameters = @{@"playerName1": playerName,
                                 @"playerName2": [NSString stringWithString:playerName],
                                 @"playerName3": [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[playerName UTF8String]],
                                 @"playerName4": [NSString stringWithCString:[playerName UTF8String] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                                 @"playerName5": [[NSString alloc] initWithString:playerName],
                                 @"playerName6": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",playerName]};


NSLog(@"postParameters: %@",postParameters);
```

and output is

```
playerName: Lëÿlã Råd Sölvê
postParameters: {
    playerName1 = "L\U00eb\U00ffl\U00e3 R\U00e5d S\U00f6lv\U00ea";
    playerName2 = "L\U00eb\U00ffl\U00e3 R\U00e5d S\U00f6lv\U00ea";
    playerName3 = "L\U00eb\U00ffl\U00e3 R\U00e5d S\U00f6lv\U00ea";
    playerName4 = "L\U00c3\U00ab\U00c3\U00bfl\U00c3\U00a3 R\U00c3\U00a5d S\U00c3\U00b6lv\U00c3\U00aa";
    playerName5 = "L\U00eb\U00ffl\U00e3 R\U00e5d S\U00f6lv\U00ea";
    playerName6 = "L\U00eb\U00ffl\U00e3 R\U00e5d S\U00f6lv\U00ea";
}
```

How can I achieve this...

Comment: May be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123984/nsdictionary-description-not-returning-utf8-characters

Comment: An NSString is always UTF characters and will preserve virtually all "foreign" characters, if they're appropriately introduced to the system to begin with.  "Odd" characters displayed on the console will often display oddly, though.  This is nothing to be concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

What you are seeing is an artefact of `NSLog` and the `description` method - the former invokes the latter to obtain the textual representation of an object for output. For `NSString` the string is displayed using Unicode.  However for `NSDictionary` contained strings are displayed using Objective-C Unicode character escape sequences, which have the form `'\Uxxxx'`.

To assure yourself all is OK you can use:

```
for (NSString *key in postParameters)
   NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", key, postParameters[key]);
```

and everything should display fine (except `playerName4` where you mess the string up yourself).

Comment: You can see this if you access one of the dictionary elements directly, `NSLog(@"%@", postParameters[@"playerName1"]);` will print correctly. Your data is fine

Comment: Just 

NSDictionary *postParameters = @{@"playerName1": playerName}
and 
NSString *value  = [postParameters ObjectForKey:@"playerName1"];
NSLog(@"%@",value); is getting the needed results